# Testing cocoa app targeted for multiple plaforms

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to cocoa and os x. I have developed an application that is meant for 10.5 and above. I have got 10.7 os x with me. Is there a way to simulate the testing without having to have real machines ? or atleast find as to at which places I am calling cocoa api which might not be available on any of the supported platforms ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access you could install VMWare Fusion and load different versions of OSX into the VM to test the application.

You could also go into your build settings and set OS X Deployment Target to different versions of OS X.  This would at least see if your application would build using that versions compiler.